# Can anyone explain me that what is happening in this code?

Tags: python, lambda

Can anyone explain me that what is happening in this code and what is getting stored in doubler and tripler.

Here is the code:

```
def myfunc(n):
  return lambda i: i*n

doubler = myfunc(2)
tripler = myfunc(3)
val = 11
print("Doubled: " + str(doubler) + ". Tripled: " + str(tripler))
```

Comment: your function returns a function... you have to call it: `str(doubler(val))` for instance

Comment: The returned functions have names of exemplary clarity. The `print` fails to call them, though. Where did you get this example? It's not a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myfunc` is a function which *creates* an anonymous function (aka `lambda`)

So `doubler` is a *function* that doubles the input.

When you're printing your statement you get the *representation* of the functions, not the result:

```
Doubled: <function myfunc.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000000003373268>. Tripled: <function myfunc.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000000033732F0>
```

You have to *call* your functions, and using the *parameter* you just defined.

```
print("Doubled: " + str(doubler(val)) + ". Tripled: " + str(tripler(val)))
```

now prints:

```
Doubled: 22. Tripled: 33
```

Comment: thanx for your valueable time abd explanation

Answer (score 0):

Returning `lambda i: i*n` you are returning a function and not a value.
You have to change your code in:

```
print("Doubled: " + str(doubler(val)) + ". Tripled: " + str(tripler(val))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function "myfunc(n)" will return you another (lambda) function, which you can call with doubler (or trippler).

```
doubler(2) returns 4
```

The variables doubler, trippler are only holding a reference of a function, so the str(doubler) does not make much sense, as it is showing you the string representation of this function, with its memory address.